# What is the cause of my connection timing out?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make a messaging program, of sorts, and I wanted to connect to my friend's PC. I told him to download server.py and run it, then when I tried to connect using client.py it timed out (the error said that his PC had failed to respond in time)...

I am sure it is my code that is the problem because we both have relatively good internet connections, and he gave the program full permissions.

server.py

```py
from socket import *
import socket
import select

## -- Server (Rooms) -- ##
users = [] # This will be used later on
addresses = [] # This will be used later on

host_name = socket.gethostname()

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(host_name) 
PORT = 12345

print(f"Server Info\nHOST: {HOST}\nPORT: {PORT}")

def user_join():
    # Append username to users[]
    # Append user address to adresses[]
    print(f"{address} connecting (nicked {username})")

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
serversocket.listen(1)
clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()

print(address)
with clientsocket:
    while True:
        Srecv = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(f"{address}: {Srecv}")
        # Add server time to message before sending
        clientsocket.sendall(Srecv.encode())
```

client.py

```py
from socket import *
import socket
import ipaddress

## -- Server (Room) -- ##
host = input("Host: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))

username = input("Username: ")
username = "<" + username + ">"
print(f"Connecting under nick \"{username}\"")

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Creates socket
clientsocket.connect((host, port)) # Connects to the server

while True:
    Csend = input("MSG: ") # Input message
    #Csend = f"{username} {Csend}" # Add username to message
    clientsocket.send(Csend.encode()) # Send message to ONLY the server

    print(clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())
```

Running both on my PC at the same time causes it to run fine, even if I run them on separate machines that are both connected to my internet it still works fine, so I don't really know why it hasn't worked on my friend's PC

Comment: ip address within a network =/= external ip address reachable by everyone. Have you done port forwarding on your router?

Comment: Also your friend's computer might have a firewall blocking connections on ports that are not explicitely allowed.

Comment: @TinNguyen No I have not done port forwarding on my router

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers He allowed everything on his firewall, I'm not sure if that would be the issue.

Comment: You need port forwarding. You can have multiple PCs in your network but to the internet you are using a single ip address. Without port forwarding you wouldn't know which machine is supposed to receive the traffic.

Comment: @TinNguyen Do I only need port forwarding (for hosting) and everyone else can connect to me? or does everyone need it?

Comment: Only the one hosting the server needs to port forward. Clients do not need port forwarding.
Since your ip address is changing you might want to look up how to buy domain names and how to configure a dynamic DNS.

Comment: @TinNguyen Ok thanks. This somewhat messes with my idea, as I wanted other people to create rooms using their PCs as servers, are there any workarounds for port-forwarding, or do I have to use it?

Comment: Most residentials have their own network hidden behind a NAT and for that port forwarding is required when they want to become reachable from the web.